# UBUNTU 12.10 loaded. after that boot sector changed from win to grub

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

After installing Ubuntu 12.10, to my PC and giving a path in the external HD, its root directory only went into that and all of the files on the HD of my PC.

Now I require the external HD every time to go to either Win or Linux. I deleted the partition made by Linux from the disk management of Windows, and now I want to change the boot sector of my HD of the PC back to Windows.

The PC is not starting up and showing a Grub failure. I have the original Win 7 OS. I tried with that going to the command line, but what is the command that takes me to DVD? I've tried 'cd dvd' and 'cd/ dvd'.

Answer (score 0):

First, if possible, create a full backup of your HD in case something goes wrong or for you to restart trying something else.

Once that is done, I'd suggest you boot from the Windows 7 DVD and try the automatic repair. It should be able to notice its own bootloader missing, and should restore the original one. If that doesn't work, tell us.

I'm not sure what "command line" you're talking about. The command line within the restore console? If so, the DVD drive should have just another letter, although there will be several drives not usually being there (created during booting from DVD to store temporary files etc.). Or are you talking about GRUB?

One more thing I wanted to mention in advance: If you'd like to try Ubuntu without risking your Windows installation or getting any system stuff modified, I'd suggest you to try [WUBI][1]. It's creating a standard Ubuntu installation using one big file on your HDD as its "hard disk". As such it's very easy to uninstall or reset and it will integrate itself into Windows' bootloader (without installing GRUB).